# c++ structure pointer cast as array interop c#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, interop

**Preface**:

I have a legacy c++ application which has a COM component. One of the methods goes

```
HRESULT foo(int* returnInteger)
```

Although the initial implementation was designed to return single int, the program evolved such that the classes which implement this, now return a list of integers instead of one.

```
returnInteger = memalloc((number of integers)*size of integer)
```

and the caller also reads the return pointer by

```
number of integers returned = sizeof(returnInteger)/size of integer
```

I know this design is not pure COM, not ideal and was not designed keeping interop in mind. But, I have to make-do with what I have.

**Current problem**:

Designing a c# application which uses the component. I know I will have to slowly phase it out, but for now, I have to continue with the same

c# shows the method as

```
foo(ref int returnInteger)
```

The c# application will read only one int (even though the c++ client is sending over an array of integers). How can I get the c# application to behave the same as the c++ client and read the array of integers?

Any help on this is much appreciated

Comment: Use BitConverter.  BitConverter will allow you to convert 4 bytes at a time to an integer and has a start index to you can convert any 4 sequentil bytes in the array.  The pointer become the startindex.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the immediate reply. Sorry for being a bit thick, but I couldn't work out how the bitconverter would help me here. I have edited the question, hopefully this will convey my problem more clearly. If BitConverter is still the way to go, can you also provide a code snippet?

Comment: Hard to help you when the function declaration is so completely incapable of returning more than one int.  At a minimum it should be int** so it can return an array, plus an int* argument to return the array size.  As long as you have to fix the code, do it the right way and return SafeArray.

Comment: @HansPassant This is what I was afraid of. Since I cannot change the legacy code, I am wondering whether a layer of Managed C++ would help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for this: Using managed C++ as a middle layer.

Although not the most ideal solution, since I could not modify the legacy code, this is the route which favored me the most.

Thanks a lot for all the help

Comment: You can get it to work in c# without middle layer if you declare the parameter IntPtr then use marshal methods.